# java swing gui only repaints after a focus change

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, repaint

i am working with swing gui.
I have a simple Jframe with a tabbed pane with two tabs.  When i click a non selected Tab, and don't move the mouse, nothing happens. i.e. the hidden tab does not appear.  But, if i click the unselected tab, then mouse over to a button(without clicking button) the tab repaints.

I also see this behavior with toggle buttons too. I toggle the text of a button based on the state but it doesn't show/repaint until i move focus to another button.

Am i supposed to be calling a repaint for the whole Jframe after every event? or am i not processing events properly?

Comment: You should not need to call `repaint()` at all after these clicks unless you're doing some graphics that is supposed to occur with button press or tab press. You've likely got a bug somewhere in your code, but where, I don't know.

Comment: If your code is in fact a simple program as you say that it is, then post it. Let us check it out. If it's large, then consider Consider creating and posting a [minimal example program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Well of course i had a bug :(.  I was calling a method to mod the button text inside a  private void formComponentShown(java.awt.event.ComponentEvent evt) function.  removing hat made the gui act normal again.  thanks!

Comment: Glad you've got it working!

Comment: Now you can either write up an answer & accept it later or delete the question.